# Cant Use TYPEORM init

Tags: npm, typeorm

I've already installed typeorm from NPM.

However, when using typeorm in CLI I'm faced with

```
'typeorm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

using NPM list I get this list of globally installed packages

```
+-- pg@8.5.1
| +-- buffer-writer@2.0.0
| +-- packet-reader@1.0.0
| +-- pg-connection-string@2.4.0
| +-- pg-pool@3.2.2
| +-- pg-protocol@1.4.0
| +-- pg-types@2.2.0
| | +-- pg-int8@1.0.1
| | +-- postgres-array@2.0.0
| | +-- postgres-bytea@1.0.0
| | +-- postgres-date@1.0.7
| | `-- postgres-interval@1.2.0
| |   `-- xtend@4.0.2
| `-- pgpass@1.0.4
|   `-- split2@3.2.2
|     `-- readable-stream@3.6.0
|       +-- inherits@2.0.4 deduped
|       +-- string_decoder@1.3.0
|       | `-- safe-buffer@5.2.1 deduped
|       `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2
`-- typeorm@0.2.31
  +-- @sqltools/formatter@1.2.2
  +-- app-root-path@3.0.0
  +-- buffer@5.7.1
  | +-- base64-js@1.5.1
  | `-- ieee754@1.2.1
  +-- chalk@4.1.0
  | +-- ansi-styles@4.3.0
  | | `-- color-convert@2.0.1
  | |   `-- color-name@1.1.4
  | `-- supports-color@7.2.0
  |   `-- has-flag@4.0.0
  +-- cli-highlight@2.1.10
  | +-- chalk@4.1.0 deduped
  | +-- highlight.js@10.7.1
  | +-- mz@2.7.0
  | | +-- any-promise@1.3.0
  | | +-- object-assign@4.1.1
  | | `-- thenify-all@1.6.0
  | |   `-- thenify@3.3.1
  | |     `-- any-promise@1.3.0 deduped
  | +-- parse5@5.1.1
  | +-- parse5-htmlparser2-tree-adapter@6.0.1
  | | `-- parse5@6.0.1 extraneous
  | `-- yargs@16.2.0 deduped
  +-- debug@4.3.1
  | `-- ms@2.1.2
  +-- dotenv@8.2.0
  +-- glob@7.1.6
  | +-- fs.realpath@1.0.0
  | +-- inflight@1.0.6
  | | +-- once@1.4.0 deduped
  | | `-- wrappy@1.0.2
  | +-- inherits@2.0.4
  | +-- minimatch@3.0.4
  | | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.11
  | |   +-- balanced-match@1.0.0
  | |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
  | +-- once@1.4.0
  | | `-- wrappy@1.0.2 deduped
  | `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.1
  +-- js-yaml@3.14.1
  | +-- argparse@1.0.10
  | | `-- sprintf-js@1.0.3
  | `-- esprima@4.0.1
  +-- mkdirp@1.0.4
  +-- reflect-metadata@0.1.13
  +-- sha.js@2.4.11
  | +-- inherits@2.0.4 deduped
  | `-- safe-buffer@5.2.1
  +-- tslib@1.14.1
  +-- xml2js@0.4.23
  | +-- sax@1.2.4
  | `-- xmlbuilder@11.0.1
  +-- yargonaut@1.1.4
  | +-- chalk@1.1.3 extraneous
  | +-- figlet@1.5.0
  | `-- parent-require@1.0.0
  `-- yargs@16.2.0
    +-- cliui@7.0.4
    | +-- string-width@4.2.2 deduped
    | +-- strip-ansi@6.0.0
    | | `-- ansi-regex@5.0.0
    | `-- wrap-ansi@7.0.0
    |   +-- ansi-styles@4.3.0 deduped
    |   +-- string-width@4.2.2 deduped
    |   `-- strip-ansi@6.0.0 deduped
    +-- escalade@3.1.1
    +-- get-caller-file@2.0.5
    +-- require-directory@2.1.1
    +-- string-width@4.2.2
    | +-- emoji-regex@8.0.0
    | +-- is-fullwidth-code-point@3.0.0
    | `-- strip-ansi@6.0.0 deduped
    +-- y18n@5.0.5
    `-- yargs-parser@20.2.7
```

What am I missing here, I'm trying to follow the steps in the installation guide but I'm stuck in the part where I would be initializing a TYPEORM project.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not install it globally.

Try running `npm install typeorm -g` and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: I restarted my computer after the step you provided just to make sure but still faced with the same error.

Comment: Do you get an error when you execute `node -v` or `npm -v`?

Comment: I do not get an error, here is what appears when I do both command:
for node -v (v14.15.4)
for npm -v (6.14.10)